# AngularJS: close modal and redirect after form submit

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-router

The bellow modal is inside a `ng-controller="myController as SignupCtrl"`

```
<div id="modalSignup" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" ng-click="SignupCtrl.resetForm()">
                    X
                </button> 
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form name="formSignup" novalidate>
                    <button type="submit" ng-click="LoginCtrl.signup();">
                        submit
                    </button> 
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm also using `ui-router` in my project.
How do I write the controller to close the modal and change state after success on `LoginCtrl.signup()` ?

Comment: You can use [ngDialog](https://github.com/likeastore/ngDialog) for dialog windows in your project. It has method `closeThisDialogWindow` in the scope

Comment: Good tip. I did ti with  `$('#modalSignup').modal('hide');` though, but still don't know how to change the state

Comment: You can call method `$state.go('your state')` and then close the modal. It should work. At least it worked for me with ngDialog

Comment: calling $stage.go before closing the modl, worked! thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [Bootstrap's JS methods](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#modals-methods) to close the modal manually.

But you are mixing jQuery and AngularJS. You should use a 3rd party library to do this.

See [UI Bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/).

Comment: I was able to close the modal with  `$('#modalSignup').modal('hide');`, but still don't know how to change state. Tried to call `$state.go('app.menu')` right after closing the modal, but it didn't work.

Comment: Following  NechiK tip, I just had to call $state.go before closing the modal, and it worked.